# Excel - Data extract from one worksheet to another spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below script to extract the data from one sheet to another sheet within the same workbook.

```
Sub Test()
Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim i As Long

With ThisWorkbook
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Set SourceSheet = Worksheets(Range("D2").Value2)
    Set TargetSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
End With

LastRow = SourceSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
LastCol = SourceSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

For i = 1 To LastRow
    For j = 1 To LastCol
        SourceSheet.Cells(i, j).Copy Destination:=TargetSheet.Cells(i + 9, j)
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

I need to extract the data to **another spreadsheet** (same directory where source files are saved) and the extracted should appear from **ROW 50** onwards.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. What did you try? That code it is working so just use the macro recorder to make your process and you will get you code immediately. Later we will be glad to help you. If you don´t know how to do it, more information is required as the workbook name, worksheet used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the workbook, into a `Workbook` object, like so

```
Sub GetDataExample()

Dim wbDest As Excel.Workbook
Dim TargetSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SourceSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open("c:\databases\csv\test1.xlsx")
Set SourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set TargetSheet = wbDest.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With SourceSheet.UsedRange

    LastRow = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    LastCol = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

    TargetSheet.Range("a50").Resize( _
                        .Rows.Count, _
                        .Columns.Count).Value = .Value

End With

wbDest.Close True

End Sub
```

Comment: My source file name is "Sales_Data" and worksheet names are "Jan_18", "Feb_18" etc. and my destination file is "Sales_Review" (.xlsm) and the worksheet name is "MON_REV". When I tried by changing the file path and sheet name it is not updating. Please let me where I did mistake.

Comment: You'll supply some more details about what happened.

Comment: Mine doesn't have next j.  Until you've posted the new code, Im afraid it's a bit of a guess :)

Comment: What I need to extract / transfer the data from one workbook to another workbook.

Comment: Showing error at ``Set TargetSheet = wbDest.Worksheets("Summary_Test")``` when exectuting